# How not recharge the mapView when reload the view?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I have a mapView into a view in my app in Swift, and when I use the navigation controller and go to other view and then return to the mapView this recharge the location.

When this view is show:

[image]

When I'm navigating and show this (loading):

[image]

There is some form to not need recharged the userLocation all time that I change to this view  and establish this location all the time?

Thanks!